# Converting string binary to int decimal

Tags: java, recursion

I need to use recursion but I can't seem to figure it out. I need to make a method to call that will convert a binary string into an int decimal form. I need to do this with recursion only. This means no global variables or loops.
Here is what I have:

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        if( convert( "1010111" ) == 57) {
            System.out.println( "test worked: 57" );
        }
        
        if( convert( "1110001" ) == 113) {
            System.out.println( "test worked: 113" );
        }
    }

    public static int convert( String temp ) {
        Integer.parseInt(temp);
        if(Integer.parseInt(temp)>0) {
            return 0;
        } 
        return temp/%100 + convert(temp*2)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> test worked : 57
>
> test worked : 113

Comment: Your code does not even compile. `temp` is a `String` and you cannot do `temp/%100` or `temp*2` on a String.

Comment: General advice: don't name a variable 'temp' unless it really is very temporary, i.e. its use lasts for only a couple of statements. In particular, a method argument is very rarely temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use recursion (as homework or exercise), here is the way you can consider:

Pseudo code:

```
int convert(String input) {
  if input is empty {
    return 0;
  }
  else {

    int lastDigit = last digit of input
    String prefix = input excluding last digit
    int result = convert(prefix) * 2 + lastDigit
  }

}
```

Comment: how do i get prefix and lastdigit?

Comment: [Substring](https://www.javatpoint.com/substring) is one possible method, there are many others. Give it a go and see what you can find out

Answer (score 1):

If the binary string is just one digit long the task is trivial.

For strings of length `n > 1`, split into the first `n-1` digits and the last digit. Find the value of the first `n-1` digits via a recursive call and then multiply that result by two and add the last digit.

Comment: for(temp>1) {
       return ((convert(temp)-1) *2)+  (int)temp%10;  
   
     }

Comment: @JamesCalhone " I need to do this with recursion only. This means no global variables or loops"

Comment: so Integer.parseInt isn't considered recursion?

Comment: No, recursion means a function is calling itself.

Comment: @JamesCalhone the recursion is, that you call convert() inside of convert(). Integer.parseInt is just a statement here.

Comment: @JamesCalhone Do you really know what recursion is?  As a questioner you need to make sure your question is accurate

Comment: i see thank you. i will try to break up the string then

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int convert( String s ) 
{
  int n = s.length();
  if(n == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(n-1)) + 2*convert(s.substring(0, n-1));
}
```

By the way, `1010111` is 87, not 57.

Comment: Given it is most probably a homework for OP, I'd rather not providing the actual code.  Instead we should only give hint for him to help him solve the question himself